# Unit testing the State

Tags: flutter

I am trying to fetch data from SharedPreferences during initState() and test it.
If I simply set private variable inside the state without invoking setState(), view is not updated.

If I try to wrap setting variables inside setState() my test will break
with null pointer at setState() method.

```
NoSuchMethodError: The method 'markNeedsBuild' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: markNeedsBuild()
```

Here is my initState()

```
initState() {
  _appRepository.readOnboardingCompleted().then((readValue) {
    print("read: $readValue");
    setState(()=>_onboardingCompleted = readValue);
});
  super.initState();
}
```

here is the test

```
test(
  'GIVEN app starts WHEN onboarding was completed THEN onboarding is disabled',() {

     when(mockAppRepository.readOnboardingCompleted()).thenReturn(mockBoolFuture);
     AppState systemUnderTest = new AppState(mockAppRepository);
     systemUnderTest.initState();
     verify(mockAppRepository.readOnboardingCompleted());
});
```

I feel there has to be an easier way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SharedPreferences.setMockInitialValues`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/shared_preferences/lib/shared_preferences.dart#L110) to initialize `SharedPreferences` with values for testing. Then you don't need to mock it yourself.

I don't think unit testing the behavior of `initState` is the right way to achieve your code coverage goals. A `State` is tied to a `StatelessWidget`. The public API of the `StatelessWidget` is its constructor arguments (input) and the render objects it produces (output). Nobody should be calling protected methods of a `State` like `initState` except for Flutter itself.

I suggest you take a look at the Flutter unit tests and see if you can write tests that are more at that level, e.g. [icon button test](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/test/material/icon_button_test.dart).

Comment: I understand that initState is called by framework but it still handles business logic so it should be possible to test it separation. I am going to try separate logic elsewhere.